# Apple HTTP Live Streaming with unmuxed H264

Tags: h.264, http-live-streaming, m3u8, m3u

Does Apple (or anyone else for that matter) support m3u files (HTTP live streaming) that reference raw H264 files?

I know VLC media player supports playback of H264 files (unmuxed), but I am wondering if Apple and VLC are smart enough to use the H264 files as a part of a HTTP live broadcast via the m3u files.

Comment: AFAIK, the answer is no. You need to have some kind of container (e.g. mp4)

Comment: For one, raw H.264 Streams have no timing information.

Comment: Ok. It seems that Apple favors MPEG-TS more than MP4. I guess I will have to mux. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct form apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html

> The media segment files are normally produced by the stream segmenter, based on input from the encoder, and consist of a series of .ts files containing segments of an MPEG-2 Transport Stream carrying H.264 video and AAC, MP3, or AC-3 audio. For an audio-only broadcast, the segmenter can produce MPEG elementary audio streams containing either AAC audio with ADTS headers, MP3 audio, or AC-3 audio.